# partial-response xml displays on browser instead of the page itself

Tags: xml, spring, jsf, primefaces, partial-response

I'm currently developing a JSF application using **Spring** and **Primefaces 4.0**. We have intermittent issues regarding the XML page being displayed instead of page itself when redirecting to other pages.

This seems to be similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178778/partial-response-view-expired-exception-or-malformed-xhtml. Also whenever this happens there are no errors printed in the logs.

**PartialResponse 1:**

```
<partial-response>
    <error>
          <error-name>class java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException</error-name>
          <error-message>
              <![CDATA[ Index: 0, Size: 0 ]]>
          <error-message>
    </error>
</partial-response>
```

**PartialResponse 2:**

```
<partial-response>
   <changes>
       <update id="javax.faces.ViewState">-4640542341950585998:4269573232206322924</update>
   </changes>
</partial-response>
```

We are currently using Omnifaces 2.0 **FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory** and we also used banterCz's **JSFRedirectStrategy** for expired session redirection in our session management filter.

[JsfRedirectStrategy.java](https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/5160269)

```
public class JsfRedirectStrategy implements InvalidSessionStrategy {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

private static final String FACES_REQUEST_HEADER = "faces-request";

private String invalidSessionUrl;

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void onInvalidSessionDetected(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {        

    boolean ajaxRedirect = "partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader(FACES_REQUEST_HEADER));
    if(ajaxRedirect) {
        String contextPath = request.getContextPath();
        String redirectUrl = contextPath + invalidSessionUrl;
        logger.debug("Session expired due to ajax request, redirecting to '{}'", redirectUrl);

        String ajaxRedirectXml = createAjaxRedirectXml(redirectUrl);
        logger.debug("Ajax partial response to redirect: {}", ajaxRedirectXml);

        response.setContentType("text/xml");
        response.getWriter().write(ajaxRedirectXml);
    } else {
        String requestURI = getRequestUrl(request);
        logger.debug("Session expired due to non-ajax request, starting a new session and redirect to requested url '{}'", requestURI);
        request.getSession(true);
        response.sendRedirect(requestURI);
    }

}

private String getRequestUrl(HttpServletRequest request) {
    StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();

    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    if (StringUtils.hasText(queryString)) {
        requestURL.append("?").append(queryString);
    }

    return requestURL.toString();
}

private String createAjaxRedirectXml(String redirectUrl) {
    return new StringBuilder()
                    .append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
                    .append("<partial-response><redirect url=\"")
                    .append(redirectUrl)
                    .append("\"></redirect></partial-response>")
                    .toString();
}

public void setInvalidSessionUrl(String invalidSessionUrl) {
    this.invalidSessionUrl = invalidSessionUrl;
}

}
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<factory>
     <exception-handler-factory>org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>1048576</param-value>
</context-param>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/error/viewexpiredpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/pagenotfound.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error/globalerrorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error/globalerrorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException</exception-type>
    <location>/error/globalerrorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException</exception-type>
    <location>/error/globalerrorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: This problem is 2-fold. 1) The particular exception is caused by a bug, but this can't be answered without seeing the full stack trace (check server logs). 2) The exception handling is not properly configured (tell how you've configured it).

Comment: Thanks for the reply BalusC. The issue seems to be intermittent as we could not replicate it consistently. We are currently using Omnifaces 2.0 FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory for handling exceptions that occurs during a JSF ajax request and as for expiring sessions we implemented banterCz's JSFRedirectStrategy for redirecting to the invalid session url (login page) whenever the session expires. Do you have an idea on what might be causing the problem ? We are currently checking if Primefaces is the one causing the said issue.

Comment: I can't continue without the stack trace.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have encountered the intermittent IndexOutOfBoundsException again. I have posted the logs here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527274/java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-index-0-size-0-unexpected-error-restori

Comment: I'm using the same components like you (JSFRedirectStrategy, FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory) and I'm running into the exception from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29178778/partial-response-view-expired-exception-or-malformed-xhtml. Sadly the question with the stacktrace is no longer available. Where you able to fix it?